# "SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY" after login in with the user ID and password

Tags: cookie

I upgraded my Cloud hosting account (doubled the processor and memory) but now - I am getting the following problem:

When a customer goes through the order process, **after they log in** - a page appears with the products, then they hit the "proceed to checkout" button but nothing happens...they click it again and then it comes up with a page that has this:

> SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY
>
> You have no items in your shopping cart.
>
> Click here to continue shopping.

I have already increased the cookie life time to 86400 under

```
Sytem -> Configuration -> Web -> Session and Cookie Management
```

I think this is a problem with the server time. We are in the Mountain Standard Time zone and the backend of Magento is set to that (MST). My hosting company is asking me what they shall **set the server time to?**